# How to prove $\gcd(a, b) = ax + by$

Tags: proof-writing, gcd-and-lcm

Let $a, b \in \mathbb N$, assume they are not both $0$. Define $L = \{n\in\mathbb N^+ \mid \exists x, y \in \mathbb{Z}: n = ax + by\}$

how do I prove the following claim:

$L$ has a minimum element $m$,  i.e. $m$ is no larger than any other element of $L$

(without assuming that $\gcd(a, b) = ax + by$)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle

Comment: Since you are allowing $x,y\in\Bbb{Z},$ the set $L$ has no minimum element.

Comment: He said the $n$ considered are only positive.

Comment: @Junkyards: I see. Thanking for pointing out that. By the way, then it is trivial. If there is no such element, then we can find an infinite descending chain of positive integers starting with a finite natural number.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$\mathbf N^*$ satisfies the well-ordering property.

Answer (score 0):

There is almost nothing to prove (except if you are redefining the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$).

Because otherwise, by the well-ordering property of $\mathbb{N}$, you just have to prove that your set is not empty.

Comment: which is trivial as $a, b \in L$.